# HTML5 Canvas access-control-allow-origin error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm getting the following javascript error when I try to get data from a canvas element:

> Error: canvas.toDataURL() not supported. [Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"...

The canvas is drawn from an image served from a different domain, but I'm using a proxy to add these 2 lines to the image response header:

> access-control-allow-origin: *
>
> access-control-allow-credentials: true

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Ted

Comment: Uhh how exactly are using your proxy. Unless you're using cross-domain iframe messaging/backend service, it's gonna fail

Comment: I'm using Charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com) on my desktop as a proxy to fiddle with the image response headers (adding the access-control-allow-origin lines). This is just for dev. If it works, I'm going to request that the image server headers be changed to have the access-control-allow-origin lines added.  <br/> My understanding was that if the image response header has the access-control-allow-origin lines, then my javascript can edit the canvas.

Comment: I finally found it. The missing piece is setting the crossOrigin property of image to "Anonymous". 

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CORS_Enabled_Image

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark yourself as the accepted answer, so that people looking for this later will more easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

To make a proper CORS request, you must set the image's [cross origin property](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/embedded-content-1.html#attr-img-crossorigin) to "Anonymous".  [This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CORS_Enabled_Image) is from the Mozilla Developer Network.

```
var img = new Image,
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    src = "http://example.com/image"; // insert image url here

img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
    localStorage.setItem( "savedImageData", canvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
}
img.src = src;
// make sure the load event fires for cached images too
if ( img.complete || img.complete === undefined ) {
    img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
    img.src = src;
}
```

The browser support excludes any known version of IE, and unreleased versions of Safari.  Firefox and Chrome have years of support.