# javascript insecure operation

Tags: javascript, operation

I have the folowing code :

```
$("#btn_trans").click(function(){
    var canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    console.log("canvasData :");
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'../rr.php',false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(canvasData );
});
```

the probleme is the navigator says that the line:
var canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
is insecure operation I did'not found what wrong with my code exactly

Comment: Is the image from another domain than your's ? see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9344660/1170900

Comment: it is not an image it is a canvas object

Comment: What did you write on your canvas ?

Comment: i merged two image in my canvas

Comment: @NejmeddineJammeli and where does these images come from ?

Comment: It looks like this can fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273537/html5-canvas-access-control-allow-origin-error#comment-16508842

Comment: come from another web  site

Comment: So see the links posted in the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788471/javascript-insecure-operation?noredirect=1#comment25948304_17788471 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788471/javascript-insecure-operation?noredirect=1#comment25948985_17788471

Comment: `../rr.php` I'm not sure this works.